# If I change the default port number (3306) of MySQL during installation, then will it cause any problem?

Tags: mysql, xampp, port, computer-science

I need to use **MySQL Community Edition 8.0CE** and **XAMPP** both of them. But **XAMPP** can't start the MySQL service, it's showing error; because **XAMPP** use the same **port (3306)** for **MySQL**, which port is using by **MySQL Workbench**.
**That is the error, which is showing in XAMPP:-**

> 01:45:09 AM  [mysql]  Problem detected! 01:45:09 AM  [mysql]  Port
> 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"! 01:45:09 AM  [mysql]     MySQL
> WILL NOT start without the configured ports free! 01:45:09 AM  [mysql]
> You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
> 01:45:09 AM  [mysql]  or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to
> listen on a different port 01:45:09 AM  [mysql]   Attempting to start
> MySQL app... 01:45:09 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
> 01:45:29 AM  [mysql]  Status change detected: stopped 01:45:29 AM
> [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. 01:45:29 AM  [mysql]
> This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,  01:45:29 AM
> [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another
> method. 01:45:29 AM  [mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs
> and check 01:45:29 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more
> clues 01:45:29 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
> 01:45:29 AM  [mysql]  entire log window on the forums

So I want to reinstall **MySQL Community Server** with different port number. *will it cause any problem? what other port number should I use?*

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely change the port without issue, but it's probably best to choose a port between 1024-49151 and avoid [registered ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Registered_ports) to prevent port conflicts.

Also note that many MySQL client libraries and programs will assume port 3306 but should always provide a way of specifying your own port.